# There is data in R package and I want them to save in excel.How I can do this

Tags: r

**using data in R Package**
There is data in R package and I want them to save in excel.How I can do this؟
thanks
Hossein

Answer (score 3):

You can easily save to a csv and then open that with Excel:

```
data(mtcars)
write.csv(mtcars, file = "fileName.csv")
```

You can look at `?write.csv` for a number of options.  The file will be written in the current working directory, which you can see with `getwd()`.  Also, depending upon your locale, you might want `write.csv2`.

Answer (score 1):

Writing to csv, as suggested, should be the easiest and fastest in general. But you really want an Excel output only so that you could save several files into one workbook, you could have a look at `library(xlsx)` package. There are other packages though.

A small illustration on the steps to save 2 datasets into 1 workbook using `xlsx` package. For more details, check `?xlsx` after loading the package.

```
new_workbook <- createWorkbook()
A <- createSheet(wb = new_workbook, sheetName = "sheet_1")
B <- createSheet(wb = new_workbook, sheetName = "sheet_2")
addDataFrame(x = dataset_1, sheet = A)
addDataFrame(x = dataset_2, sheet = B)
```